# The Role-Based Access Control in Power-BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, rbac

This is the Sample dashboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3jJ1.png)

The data model has been developed using the following tables, and the SalesData table has been used to visualize configurations. The User table has been used to manage the role-based access control in the model.

1. SalesData table
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1iU2.png)
2. User table
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itYhc.png)

Data model:

SalesData[MapUser] and User[Salesman] columns have been used to create relationships between the SalesData and User tables.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqe7W.png)

Requirement:

The manager's role only needs to see Visual 1, the supervisor's role only needs to see Visual 2, and the salesman's role only needs to see Visual 3. Additionally, the salesman should only have visibility of the unit quantity sold by themselves.

Question:

RLS is setuped as follows but that way not the right pathway to fulfill the requirements.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms891.png)

I am seeking the best approach suggestions to meet the requirements without the need for creating additional tables for visual configuration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.